How to perform operations on Grandchild using Builders?
For example I have a collection of Parent(s):
class Parent{
public string ParentKey {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<Child> Children {get;set;}
}

class Child{
public string ChildKey {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<GrandChild> GrandChildren {get;set;}
}

class GrandChild {
public string GrandChildKey {get;set;}
public IEnumerable<GreatGrandChild> GreatGrandChildren {get;set;}
}

class GreatGrandChild {
public string GreatGrandChildKey {get;set;}
public string SomeValue {get;set;}
}

I can do some push and pull on the Child level like this:
var filter = Builders<Parent>.Filter.Eq(p => p.ParentKey, "some-parent-key");
var pushDefinition = Builders<Parent>.Push(p => p.Children, newChild);

But I can't figure out how to perform any operation from the GrandChildren and deeper. At least I have an idea about the filter I can use:
var filter = Builders<Parent>.Filter.And(
Builders<Parent>.Filter.Eq(p => p.ParentKey, "some-parent-key"),
Builders<Parent>.Filter.ElemMatch(p => p.Children,
Builders<Child>.Filter.Eq(c => c.ChildKey, "some-child-key"))
);

UPDATE
I found out I can using string for the path of the target field, but I'd rather want to use something like Lambda for easier refactoring:
var pushDefinition = Builders<Parent>.Push("Children.$.GrandChildren", newGrandChild);


You should need a nested .ElemMatch to accessing and comparing the nested element.
var filter = Builders<Parent>.Filter.And(
    Builders<Parent>.Filter.Eq(p => p.ParentKey, "<parentKey>"),
    Builders<Parent>.Filter.ElemMatch(p => p.Children,
        Builders<Child>.Filter.And(
            Builders<Child>.Filter.Eq(c => c.ChildKey, "<childKey>"),
                Builders<Child>.Filter.ElemMatch(c => c.GrandChildren,
                    Builders<GrandChild>.Filter.Eq(c => c.GrandChildKey, "<grandChildKey>")
                )
        )
    )
);

For pushing the new instance into the nested array (I demonstrate the example for pushing an element into the greatGrandChildren array), you need to work with $[<identifier>] (positional filtered operator.
var pushDefinition = Builders<Parent>.Update.Push("children.$[c].grandChildren.$[gc].greatGrandChildren", 
    <new GreatGrandChild instance>);

var result = await _collection.UpdateOneAsync(filter, pushDefinition,
    new UpdateOptions
    {
        ArrayFilters = new[]
        { 
            new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(
                new BsonDocument("c.childKey", childKey)
            ),
            new BsonDocumentArrayFilterDefinition<BsonDocument>(
                new BsonDocument("gc.grandChildKey", grandChildKey)
            ),
        }
    });


That's what I figured out too, but is there a way to use Lamda or something instead of string for the path for easier refactoring? my remedy for now is using nameof() with string interpolation. but I'm not yet satisfied with this workaround.

I think until now, yet MongoDB .NET Driver still don't provide us the elegant way to work the update with array filters in LINQ way: https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/CSHARP-588
